# TypeError('Unrecognized keyword arguments: ' + str(kwargs)) # Validate user data

Tags: python, keras

```
model.fit(inputs(ACC_LIST,GYRO_LIST),outputs=labels,batch_size=1,validation_split=0.2, epochs=2,verbose=1 ,shuffle=False)
```

> error    TypeError('Unrecognized keyword arguments: ' + str(kwargs))
>   1351     1352         # Validate user data.
>
> TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'inputs':
>   ([[0.15242325258914946

I try my best to fiind the question, but it doesn't work.

The model has two inputs. Respectively, for the acceleration of xyz, gyroscope xyz, the shape is 200 * 3. The output is two-dimensional x,y coordinates，the shape is 200*2

The following is the acceleration's data:

> ([[0.15242325258914946, -0.03476163517936892, -0.2969868529378741],
>   [0.5273979067752359, 0.17251581054654674, 0.15189385692567248],
>   [0.3185013507990653, 0.1020899509564357, 0.5018364082790421],
>   [-0.48467997082426617, -0.3683816236617554, 0.0820271783467561]......

Comment: we would need to see the code for the model to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
model.fit(x=[ACC_LIST,GYRO_LIST],y=labels,batch_size=1,validation_split=0.2, epochs=2,verbose=1 ,shuffle=False)
```

where `ACC_LIST` = a numpy array of your accelerometer data and `GYRO_LIST` = numpy array of your gyroscope data

Comment: Sure thing! Glad that helps